# Skype web control canvas is not visible

Tags: javascript, chat, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I was trying web control for my website and even after adding the script and the code for the button, the button won't appear at all.

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-contact-id="Myskypename"></div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

I have also tried doing it on a blank new html page and still it won't appear.
No errors in the console as well.

Browser: Google Chrome

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: What browser please?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am sorry. The browser is google chrome

Comment: As somebody already asked you, did you created `YOUR_BOT_ID`?

Comment: I am instead using data-contact-id with my username

Answer (score 0):

Have you created bot and added real YOUR_BOT_ID ?

Comment: I am instead using data-contact-id with my skype username